# Как изменить кодировку в Build-строке Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text

Как можно изменить кодировку в Build-строке Sublime Text?

```
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__CreateWindowExW@48 � �㭪樨 _wWinMain@16.
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__ShowWindow@8 � �㭪樨 _wWinMain@16.
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__GetMessageW@16 � �㭪樨 _wWinMain@16.
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__TranslateMessage@4 � �㭪樨 _wWinMain@16.
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__DispatchMessageW@4 � �㭪樨 _wWinMain@16.
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__PostQuitMessage@4 � �㭪樨 "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z).
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__BeginPaint@8 � �㭪樨 "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z).
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__FillRect@12 � �㭪樨 "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z).
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__EndPaint@8 � �㭪樨 "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z).
wind-675db7.o : error LNK2019: ��뫪� �� ��ࠧ�襭�� ���譨� ᨬ��� __imp__DefWindowProcW@16 � �㭪樨 "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z).
```

[image: Скриншот]